# Solutions for First-Launch Tutorial for a Cocoa Application

Tags: macos, cocoa

What are the tools available for designing user-friendly tutorials for guiding users in using your app (on top of Apple Help Books which are more for the days-to-days questions) at first launch like a lot of app seems to have ?

As you can imagine, I tried every Google query I could think of but using `framework cocoa tutorial` is only giving tutorial on how to develop a Cocoa Framework ;)

Comment: I haven't seen a framework for it, you can either make a translucent image overlay or position arrows or whatever programmatically.

Comment: @Kevin Would you have any ressources, examples to direct me to so as to make an answer out of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying out out what I think is a pretty elegant solution using a NSPopover-based approach and, since I'm new to Github, I thought it would be a nice occasion to sourcing a project; so here it is :

## BCFirstLaunchTutorial

Source : [BCFirstLaunchTutorial on Github](https://github.com/bertrand-caron/BCFirstLaunchTutorial)

[image]

Tutorials are made out of a succession of NSPopovers appearing, pointing to objects and displaying a text of your choosing. The next NSPopover object is displayed when the previous one is closed.

NB : The object hosting the NSPopover needs to be able to respond to `@selector(bounds)` to be usable.

Events are added to the tutorial like this :

```
[myPopoverController    addEventWithObject: myTextView
        andText:@"This is my TableView. Close this Popover to open the next one."];
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is actually no built in functionality for this.
But I'm sure you will have absolutely no trouble implementing it yourself.

You can use `NSUserDefaults` for this task.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isNotFirstLaunch"]) {
        // This is the first launch! Do whatever you want

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isNotFirstLaunch"];
    }
}
```

So, for example you can show a window with information about how to use it.
Obviously, you would need to create that `ITFirstLaunchWindowController` class.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isNotFirstLaunch"]) {
        self.firstLaunchWindowController = [ITFirstLaunchWindowController new];
        [self.firstLaunchWindowController showWindow:self];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isNotFirstLaunch"];
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT

Does this help at all?

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"First Launch!"
                                 defaultButton:@"Try!"
                               alternateButton:@"No thanks, I don't like being nice"
                                   otherButton:nil
                     informativeTextWithFormat:@"Hey, Try out this awesome feature!"];

if ([alert runModal] == NSAlertDefaultReturn) {
    // The "Try!" button was clicked
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ourwebsite.com/newFeature"]];
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the coding part, what about the graphic one ? How could I highlight features for instance ? Just flashing view ins ?

Comment: @Heisennberg I'm not quite sure what you mean. So you'd like to know how to show views and windows?

Comment: Gonna try to rephrase : I was thinking about maybe urging the user to try a feature by displaying bubble messages "Hey, Try out this awesome feature !"(for instance, the Facebook "tutorials" user have been given for the last couples of updates to guide you though the new feature). Truth be told, I haven't given it much thought yet, was just wanting to make sure there was nothing available out there. Could make a nice github project ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'am actually coming up with a pretty elegant solution using NSPopovers (didn't know about these guys, they rock!). Gonna refine the code and post it here when it's finalized in a couple of days. Feel free to challenge yourself to it too ;)

Comment: @Heisennberg Cool. Remember that the reason I cannot give a more specific answer is because you did not ask a more specific question. If you want to know more about `NSPopover`, do a Google search or post another question. Up-voting and accepting would be appreciated.